# Glassfish caching LDAP passwords

Tags: java, authentication, caching, ldap, glassfish

I have some java code which allows users to reset their passwords stored on a LDAP server.  The code runs as part of a web application running on Glassfish.

The problem I'm seeing is that after calling the change password operation, the user can subsequently use either password to access the application.

I have a unit test which runs directly against the LDAP server and I can verify that the password did indeed change and the user cannot gain access using the old password.  The problem is not on the LDAP server.

What I've noticed is that if I restart Glassfish after the password change operation, only the new password is valid (as expected).  I'm guessing that Glassfish is caching the credentials somewhere.

What do I need to set in Glassfish (or maybe in my web.xml) to either

1. tell Glassfish not to cache the LDAP credentials
2. reset the Glassfish password cache

Thanks in advance....

**UPDATE**
Still having this problem.  I also thought that the browser could be storing this information, but that doesn't seem to be the case.  I close out of my browser session and both passwords still work in the new session - even with different types of browsers.  BTW - I don't know if it matters or not, but this is HTTP basic authentication.

**UPDATE**
We are also using the single sign on functionality included with Glassfish.  From [this article](http://docs.sun.com/app/docs/doc/820-4336/beacq?a=view), it looks as if the session is tied to a cookie on the browser and maybe the user would be valid until the cookie expired?  It looks as if the cookie is tied to a session.  Getting closer to figuring this out....

Comment: Seeing this exact same problem, would love to know if you figured out how to solve it.  It's not related to a cookie because we use a session cookie (i.e. it expires when you close the browser) and even after restarting the browser it will accept the old password, so clearly Glassfish is to blame here.

Comment: No - never figured it out.  I was sure it was a Glassfish issue as well.  We changed our approach to use OpenAM which doesn't seem to exhibit this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this property to your ldap realm's additional properties:

```
com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool=false
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked for my similar issue.  My GlassFish EE form authentication web app was allowing a successful login even when the account was locked (confirmed with a separate LDAP client, Jxplorer) on the LDAP server.  After setting this property the web app no longer allows logins for LDAP locked accounts.

Answer (score 0):

Could be your problem related to this Active Directory issue?

http://support.microsoft.com/?id=906305

My problem was.